# Selenium-rc Python client : Not able to iterate through the xpath?

Tags: python, selenium-rc

I am a newbie to Selenium and is implementing selenium-rc with Python client library. I tried traversing through my page's div using xpath(s) elements using the command "sel.get_xpath_count(xpath)".

It gives a count of 20, but when I iterate through every div using for statement and command "sel.get_text(xpath='%s[%d]'%(xpath, i))", but it only finds the first element and give a error on the remaining 19 saying divs not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second XPath expression is wrong.  Programmers trained in C-style languages frequently make this mistake, because they see `[...]` and think "index into an array", but that's not what brackets do in XPath.

If you use `sel.get_xpath_count(something)`, then you need to use `sel.get_text("xpath=(something)[item_number]")`.  Note the use of parentheses around the original XPath expression in the second use.

The reason behind this is that `something[item_count]` is short-hand for `something AND position() = item_count` - thus you wind up adding another predicate to the "something" expression, instead of selecting one of the nodes selected by the expression.  `(something)[item_count]` works because the value of `(something)` is a list of nodes, and adding a `position() = item_count` selects the node **from the list** with the specified position.  **That's** more like a C-style array.